# Angular and FabricJS class variables and events

Tags: angular, fabricjs

I need access to my class variable from event handler but it doesnt working. I tried use this.i, but it doesnt working too;

```
export class FirstClass{    
  i:number;

  circle:any;

  constructor(){

    circle = new fabric.Circle({left:100,top:100,radius:30});

    circle.on("mousedown",function(){i++;});
  }
}
```

Comment: `this` and `arrow function` to the rescue

Answer (score 0):

Change `circle.on("mousedown",function(){i++;});` to `circle.on("mousedown",function(){this.i++;});`. Any reference to a "top level" variable (in the class but not in a local function) must be referred to via `this.`.

Typescript is strongly typed Javascript, meaning you cant loosely refer to variables like you tried in your code.

Comment: I think that when i will use this like you, this will referre to circle and no to  FirstClass.

Comment: using `this.` inside a class will refer to anything on the "top level" of the class, meaning doing `this.` inside the constructor will let you use `this.i` and `this.circle`

Comment: I am not sure becouse something like that change fill of circle:  
constructor(){ this.circle.on("mouse:down",function(){this.set("fill","red")});
In this case in event handler function this referre to circle no to class.